# Is there a way to reach an object in another app?

Tags: macos

I would like to know if there’s a way to query another app’s object.

For example, in my app, I can write something like this

```
NSArray * myWindow = NSApp.windows;
```

to access all my app windows.

But what if I want to access the windows of another app?

Is there a way to query the classes or objects of another app?

Comment: back in the early 90's yes for some apps with some nice but not documented code. Today no, if the app is not of your own dev group.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I was expecting a negative answer. I spent hours reading, testing and coding trying to find a way but didn't find a way. I contacted Apple to see if I there's someway to achieve my goal. If so, I'll come back here.